# Python Scrapy creating new rows for yield array

Tags: python, arrays, scrapy, yield

I'm new to Python and Scrapy but have a developed working script for scraping urls read from a csv. This currently returns the urls and an array for each field, which I want to be listed on new rows for each url. Can anyone point help me achieve this?

What i'm trying to achieve is :

```
roleA, locatonA, linkA, url1 
roleB, locatonB, linkB, url1 
roleC, locatonC, linkC, url1 
roleA, locatonA, linkA, url2
```

etc.

What i currently have is:

```
[roleA,roleB, roleC...],[locationA,locationB,locationC ...],[linkA,linkB,linkC...], url1
[roleA,roleB, roleC...],[locationA,locationB,locationC ...],[linkA,linkB,linkC...], url2
[roleA,roleB, roleC...],[locationA,locationB,locationC ...],[linkA,linkB,linkC...], url3
```

Current code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import scrapy


def read_csv():
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    return(df['URLS'].values.tolist())


class Crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in read_csv():
            yield scrapy.Request(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'role': response.xpath(
                "/html//div[@class='opening']/a[@data-mapped='true']/text()").extract(),
            'location': response.xpath(
                "/html//div[@class='opening']/span/text()").extract(),
            'link': response.xpath(
                "/html//div[@class='opening']/a[@data-mapped='true']/@href").extract(),
            'url': response.url
        }
```

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. This is rather simple - one `yield item` is one line in your csv.
So you need to add a cycle in your parse function. Something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
    openings = response.css('.opening')
    for o in openings:
        item = {}
        item['role'] = o.css('a[data-mapped=true]::text').get()
        item['location'] = o.css('span::text').get()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```